# Replacing live with on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a fiddle that perfectly solves my problem. However fiddle uses old jquery live function which was removed in 1.9 I want to replace live with another alternative (on function). But simply changing the word live with on is not working. Can any one help please?
http://jsfiddle.net/Fc3ET/3/

Here is the small portion of the code in question:

```
 $('#remove').live('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
    });
```

Regards,
Ahmar

Comment: `$(documentation).on('reading',getANSWER)`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the selector parameter that allows you to use delegated events.

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
});
```

Where `document` can be replaced by any `#remove` container that exists at binding time

Answer (score 2):

Well looking at your JSFiddle, you cannot attach an event handler to `$('#remove')`  because there is no div with id "remove" since it is created after you click the add button.

As Claudio said in his answer, you can use event delegation to avoid the issue.